Book series about a guy who wins the lottery and builds an elaborate post-apocalyptic bunker
This is a series of books about a guy who wins the lottery and spends the money to build a huge and elaborate bunker to survive an apocalyptic event.
I thought it might have been written by Boyd Craven but I can't find it in his works.  I also thought that it was just called Bunker but I can't find it that way either.

Was there actually an apocalypse? Or other sci-fi or fantastic elements? Because otherwise, that feels like it might be an entirely mundane story.

Lottery-funded post-apocalyptic bunker seems to be a popular trope in self-published "thriller" type novels, it seems.

The books that I am looking for are a fairly numerous series... not a single novel. I don't recall the apocalyptic "event" but I'm certain that it was NOT a pandemic. As the series continued, the "bunker" defended itself against various opponents and then, finally, "buttoned-up" when it was overrun.

Equally, A google search for "novel, bunker, lottery, apocalypse" turned up the Final Dawn series by Darrell Maloney
From an Amazon review:

Mark is a security expert and Hannah is a scientist, and they are shocked to have won the Powerball jackpot. Before they get a chance to think about how rich they have become, Hannah is demoted at work for telling her bosses that an asteroid is on collision course with Earth and will hit in under 2 years. Hannah realises that it is being covered up so the public will know nothing until it hits, to avoid panic, while the chosen government people hide in newly constructed bunkers. She also realises that others in her department were demoted for the same reason. Now Hannah and Mark decide to build their own bunker for family and friends.



A google search for "novel, bunker, lottery, apocalypse" turned up the After Z series (5 books) by J.S. Patrick

For a decade now the world has known of the existence of the Immuno-Degenerative and Epidermal Decomposition Virus (Strain 2). The world governments and several civilian agencies have, so far, managed to keep the unimaginable from happening by keeping outbreaks under control and preventing a global pandemic. But even the best control measures seem to be falling short as outbreaks become more frequent and larger in scale.100% of those infected with ImDED2 die. The problem is they don’t stay dead. The virus hijacks their bodies, turning them into insatiable, cannibalistic eating machines…Zombies.
Ryan Maxwell, a retired soldier, and his wife, Victoria, a high school science teacher, have sacrificed for years to provide a good life for their family. But even the hardest working couple can run up against hard times. However, a spur-of-the-moment purchase of a lottery ticket is about to change their lives forever… And possibly save them all. Will the Maxwell’s be able to take advantage of their new found wealth in time to form a buffer of safety between their family and friends and the possibility of a global zombie apocalypse? Is there enough money to buy safe passage in a world… After Z?


